# How to remove particular webpart from the .wsp file in visual studio2013

Tags: web-part, visual-studio-2013

I'm developing 5 web-part in single solution for share point 2013. ever thing work fine. suddenly one of my web part currently not working due to free version is change to buy for cost. so now i want to remove the particular web part from the solution.

below my web part structure:

[image]

i need to remove online weather web part only.

I try below methods:-

Go to Features and select weather web part from feature then i move right to left back. but it's not working for me.

any other way to remove the particular web part. due to this issue share point page home page not opening. b'cos particular web part present in home page.

Answer (score 1):

Append `?contents=1` to your page address in browser address bar. You will be taken to webpart maintenance page. Here you can select the webpart and delete it. Suppose your page address is `http://yoursite.default.aspx`. Your modified adress should be `http://yoursite.default.aspx?contents=1`

Answer (score 0):

To remove the webpart from thw home page, open your site with SharePoint Designer, go to the home page and edit it in advanced mode (this may check out your page), find the weather webpart code and remove it, then save your page and check in it (if it has been checked out). Your page should now load correctly.

Comment: I try to edit but same error msg shown. 
RightClick - > Edit file in advance mode -> Edit page layout

Comment: What's the shown error?  Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: weather web part taken from   "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/"                                                        Error MSG:- The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

[WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel.]                                                                                                   SP2013FWK.UEs.Intranet.SPItems.WebParts.OnlineWeather.UEOnlineWeather.UEOnlineWeather.CreateChildControls() +161

Comment: I'm talking about the error when you delete the webpart code from the page. Did you tried it using SharePoint designer?

Comment: same error present in sharepoint designer

Comment: Ok, try to checkout the page and click on edit file in advanced mode > edit and not edit page layout.